# SupportMapFragment -- map fragment visibility

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

My problem comes when I try to show() and hide() multiple map fragments. The map does not change using show()/hide(). the fragment can be removed or hidden but keeps in the screen(dirty).

Screen: 
[image]

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43475) Related Issue

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Are you using this fragment in conjunction with the ActionBar compatibility classes found in the v4 support jar?

Comment: Thanks for response..I'm not using any ActionBar Compatibility classes..

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue when I try to switch fragments using animations... did you find some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with overlapping maps belonging to different fragments.

These two thins helped me:

- `map:zOrderOnTop="false"` on the small map.
- I was using `DialogFragment`s and calling `dismiss()` did the trick, but if you're using plain `Fragment`s. you can try to remove the fragment with the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of Android? SDK? Maps?

Try to update:   http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/09/google-maps-for-android-gets-updated-with-promised-interface-refresh-functionality-enhancements/

Might be a known issue:   https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027&q=fragment&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal